# Jplayer Dynamic playlist

Tags: jquery, asp-classic, jplayer

I have read some articles about it but they are all in javascript/php...i need to create a dynamic playlist in javascript and ASP. Is that possible? I have to take my videos from a folder in the server. I use jplayer (NOT jwplayer)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. You can generate a JSON object on the server and supply this object to a [playlist](http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-02-jPlayerPlaylist/). You can render that JSON when a page is loading or request it from a wevservice/handler/controller/whatever and use `playlistObject.setPlaylist(...)` after.